# finding if a string is contained in any of the strings in an enum

Tags: java

I have a weird problem that I am trying to solve,

I have a enum with a string something like this

```
public enum Enumm{
    Item1("i1"),
    Item2("i2");


    private String itemText;
    private Enumm(String inText){
        this.setitemText(inText);
    }
//  getter and setter for itemText not typing 
}
```

now in the other class I want to check if a string inputString contains either "i1" or "i2" but the problem is I cannot use a loop.

I know I can do this

```
 for(Enumm item: Enumm.values()){
        if (inputString.contains(item.getItemText)) {
           // do something
        }
   }
```

but the constraints of my problem do not allow me to do it this way

I am looking for something like

```
if(inputString.contains(Enumm.Item1.getItemText||Enumm.Item2.getItemText)){
   //do something
}
```

but is also dynamic such that it finds all the items in the enum
could anyone help me find a solution ?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is it that you cannot use a loop?

Comment: @PaulVargas looks like it, considering OP said "constraints of my problem"

Comment: @nvy did any of the answers here help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a static method to your enum called something like `findInString(String s)` that does the loops over the `values()` for you and returns a boolean if it finds it.  But it depends on why you are trying to avoid the loop.  Obviously, this does nothing except squirrels the loop away where you can't see it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an Item list/array and then parse through the array to check for i1 or i2.

`Item[] string = {"i1","i2"}`

```
if(string.contains("i1")||string.contains("i2"))
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help?

```
List<String> list = Collections.list(enumeration);
boolean b = list.contains("Searchstring");
```